# Failed to execute ‘postMessage’, problem with autoplay youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im trying do auto play in YT videos and received the msg below:

Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided (‘https://www.youtube.com’) does not match the recipient window’s origin (‘http://localhost:8000’).

```
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '360',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0,  'Origin': 'http://localhost:8000'  },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
      'onError': onPlayerError
    },
    host: 'https://www.youtube.com'
  });
}
```

Ive tryed follow tips on internet using https, using playerVars {origin or Origin}, host but nothing was effective... Im receiving Cross-Origin Request Blocked. I enabled in httpd.conf with:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization"
```

but still not working.